# How to Recover My database From Old WampServer?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, upgrade, wamp

Previously I am using **wampserver2** with "**mysql5.6.17**" version.I have many database in that version.
I uninstall the wampserver and install new latest version **wampserver3.1.0_x64**.

Before uninstalling my old wamp i copied all files to another drive. so i have some safe backup.

Now i want all database from old wampserver.

Is there any ways to do that..

Comment: Do you know what version of MySQL the old Wamp included?  Does Wamp have tips on upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, I will say that I am not familiar with wampserver but I am familiar with MySQL and LAMP.

First things first, are your tables within your databases MyISAM, InnoDB or a mixture of both? - You can tell on the file level by looking at the suffixes.

MyISAM tables have the table name with the following suffixes:

1. .frm
2. .MYD
3. .MYI

InnoDB tables have the table name with the following suffixes:

1. .frm
2. .ibd

If they are MyISAM, copy the tables straight into the new MySQL database directory and this will work as long as the files have the correct read write permissions and ownership (mysql).

If you have InnoDB tables then this will be an issue because you can't simply copy them into a location, in this case what you would have wanted to do is:

1. MySQL dump the databases, then MySQL import
2. Convert them to MyISAM across the board, make a  copy of the file system, then move them into the new database directory, then change back to InnoDB if needed.

** Please note, do not copy the mysql db if you have it within your backup into the new MySQL directory because this will cause all sorts of issues.